# How to dynamically add a class to an HTMLCollection (problem converting HTMLCollection into an array)?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop, htmlcollection

```
content = document.getElementsByClassName('outercontent');
```

produces an HTMLCollection of the targeted div element.

I'm trying to add a string at each index from the array `admin1` to the classList of each div at each index.

```
for(var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
  content[i].classList.add(admin1[i]);
}
```

When I console.log `content` now, I can see the new class added - however it only displays the first string in the `admin1` array for all divs.

I've read that you can't use a for loop on HTMLCollections, so I tried to convert `content` into an array here:

```
var contentarr = [...content];
```

But when I console.log `contentarr`, I see it only has a length of 1 (index 0).

(This may have something to do with the fact that only one of these divs exists in the html initially until it is multiplied ng-repeat (angularjs)?)

So how can I convert the HTMLCollection into an array and then add the classes from the `admin1` array?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

More context-

```
var subdivs2 = [];
var subdivs2 = angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng- 
controller="mainCtrl"]')).scope().subdivisions2

for(var i = 0; i < subdivs2.length; i++) {
  subdivs2[i] = subdivs2[i]["province"];
}

var admin1 = [];
for(var i = 0; i < subdivs2.length; i++) {
  admin1[i] = subdivs2[i][0]["name"];
}
```

I have a nested array in my angular controller called `subdivisions2`. I put all values of the key called "name" into an the `admin1` array.

admin1 looks like this:

```
0: "Adrar"
1: "Algiers"
2: "Annaba"
3: "Aïn Defla"
4: "Aïn Témouchent"
5: "Batna"
6: "Biskra"
7: "Blida"
8: "Bordj Bou Arréridj"
9: "Boumerdès"
10: "Bouïra"
11: "Béchar"
12: "Béjaïa"
13: "Chlef"
14: "Constantine"
15: "Djelfa"
16: "El Bayadh"
17: "El Oued"
18: "El Taref"
19: "Ghardaïa"
20: "Illizi"
21: "Jijel"
22: "Khenchela"
23: "Laghouat"
24: "M'Sila"
25: "Mascara"
26: "Mila"
27: "Mostaganem"
28: "Médéa"
29: "Naâma"
30: "Oran"
31: "Ouargla"
32: "Oum el-Bouaghi"
33: "Relizane"
34: "Saïda"
35: "Sidi Bel Abbès"
36: "Skikda"
37: "Souk Ahras"
38: "Sétif"
39: "Tamanghasset"
40: "Tiaret"
41: "Tindouf"
42: "Tipaza"
43: "Tissemsilt"
44: "Tizi Ouzou"
45: "Tlemcen"
46: "Tébessa"
```

Interestingly, when I view the HTMLCollection, it says 'length: 47' at the bottom  (same length as admin1). But when I put console.log(content.length); it says 1. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is that you only have one loop** and that loop is iterating over the HTML elements just fine, but as it goes over each (just one time), it only adds the style from the current loop index.

**You need two loops here,** one to go through the elements and another to go through the styles while still on the element.

Here's an example:

```js
let classes = ["big","bold","blue"];

// First, get all the elements you'll want to work with.
// Don't use .getElementsByClassName! Use .querySelectorAll()
let els = document.querySelectorAll(".special");

// You can use regular counting loops on HTMLCollections, but
// Arrays offer more robust looping without you having to manage 
// indexes. So, we'll convert the collection to an array:
els = Array.prototype.slice.call(els);

// Loop over the elements array
els.forEach(function(el){
   
   // Now, while we are on just one of the elements,
   // start a second loop to go over the string array
   classes.forEach(function(cls){
      // Add the class to the element that we're currently looping over
      el.classList.add(cls);
   });

});
```

```css
.big { font-size:2em; }
.bold { font-weight:bold; }
.blue { color:blue; }
```

```html
<div class="special">Some Content</div>
<p>Some Content</p>
<div>Some Content</div>
<p class="special">Some Content</p>
<div class="special">Some Content</div>
<p>Some Content</p>
<div>Some Content</div>
<p>Some Content</p>
```

**NOTE: [Don't use `.getElementsByClassName()`!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474)**

Comment: This half works! The only problem is my 'content' array (or 'els' in your example) only has a length of one, meaning that all the 47 classes get added to the one item at index 0. Because i'm using angular's ng-repeat maybe I need to use a setTimeout to make sure this occurs after all the divs have been loaded

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I solved it - the problem was I needed to use a delay to wait for the divs to multiply. My original for loop does the job (adding one unique class per div).